# Objective-C: How to use calling child's version of a method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've run into this need before. Right now, I have a function that is called every 0.1 seconds to check on how much time has elapsed. If it exceeds the "total time" (which it retrieves from the `getTotalTime` function) it stops. The `getTotalTime` method is overridden in the children. The code for the function called every 0.1 seconds is also overridden, but the original method in the parent class that uses `getTotalTime` is called using `super`, only it needs to call the child's method of `getTotalTime` instead of its own. This is, of course, the issue. I could rewrite the code from the parent in each of the children, but that seems stupid. Some Google searching has show solutions in other languages, but not in Objective-C. Is there a way to do this? If not, what are some alternatives?

Comment: Well that's called inheritance... And it exits in objective-c. One more thing, if you want to call your children's method. Be sure to create objects from that class (children) and not the parents.

Comment: Show us the code of `getTotalTime` and “the function called every .1 seconds”.  Show us both the superclass and subclass versions.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking for show us your code or an example like it. Calling getTotalTime in you parent class will call the child method if you call it like [self getTotalTime].

Comment: I agree with @robmayoff -- this would be a much better question if you provided code that illustrates what you're asking about. I provided a simple version that *I think* reproduces the situation you're talking about, but I really shouldn't have had to do that (and I'm still not sure that I understood you correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code for the function called every 0.1 seconds is also overridden,
>   but the original method in the parent class that uses getTotalTime is
>   called using super, only it needs to call the child's method of
>   getTotalTime instead of its own.

Your question is difficult to parse, but it sounds like you've got something like this:

```
@interface A : NSObject // the "parent" class
- (void) timerMethod;
- (NSDate*) getTotalTime;
// other methods as necessary
@end

@interface B : A // the "child" class
// only has overrides of A's methods
@end

@implementation A
- (void) timerMethod
{
    NSLog(@"[A timerMethod]: the time is: %@", [self getTotalTime]);
}

- (NSDate *) getTotalTime
{
    return [NSDate date];
}
@end

@implementation B
- (void) timerMethod
{
    NSLog(@"[B timerMethod]: the time is: %@", [self getTotalTime]);
    [super timerMethod];
}

- (NSDate *) getTotalTime
{
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];  // 3600 == an hour from now
}
```

I think what you're concerned about is that B's `-timerMethod` calls A's `-timerMethod`, and that in turn calls `[self getTotalTime]`, so you think that A's `-getTotalTime` will always be the one to be called. Rest easy, that's not how inheritance works. If you have an instance of B and you call one of B's methods, then `self` represents a pointer to that instance of B, *even in the context of an inherited method*. That is, `self` points to the same object even in one of A's methods. So, if you have a timer that sends `-timerMethod` to an instance of B, here's what happens:

- B's `-timerMethod` gets called.
- that method calls [super timerMethod], which results in a call to A's `-timerMethod`
- A's `-timerMethod` calls `[self getTotalTime]`, and since `self` is a pointer to an instance of B, B's `-getTotalTime` is called

So, if your timer sends its message to an instance of B, you should get two log statements, both of which have the time one hour from now:

> [B timerMethod]: the time is: *current time + 1 hour*
>
> [A timerMethod]: the time is: *current time + 1 hour*

If your timer sends its message to an instance of A, however, you'll get only one log statement, and it'll have the current time:

> [A timerMethod]: the time is: *current time*

The ability to "override" methods in subclasses like this is one of the key features that makes inheritance useful; subclasses can modify or entirely replace behaviors from the superclass, and the code in the superclass will automatically call the overridden method instead of its own method in instances of a subclass.

So, the answer to your title question...

> How to use calling child's version of a method?

is simply to use `self` whenever you want the method provided by the current object.